# Partition of minimal generating set

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, finitely-generated, free-abelian-group

Let $G$ be a finitely generated abelian group with a minimal generating set $S$. Is it possible to find a partition of $S$ to $\{A,B\}$ such that $A$ generates a free abelian subgroup, and $ B $ generates a finite abelian subgroup?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: @DerekHolt isn't a simply a matter of picking $A$ to have infinite order generators and $B$ to have finite order generators?

Comment: @freakish No. Assuming $G$ is infinite, It is possible for every element of $S$ to have infinite order (but not the other way round).

Comment: @user1729 so? $B$ doesn't have to be non-empty as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @freakish Still no, as $A$ is required to be free abelian. That is: if $G$ is finitely generated and infinite but not free abelian, then there exists a set $S$ which does not partition like the question asks.

Comment: I guess we have given the OP enough hints now!

Comment: @user1729 Thanks for your comment. Do you have any counter example, that is not preserving this partiotion?

Comment: @David If you read the comments then you should be able to find a counterexample yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=\langle x\rangle\times\langle y\rangle\cong C_\infty\times C_2$ and take $S=\{x,xy\}$. There is no partition $S=A\cup B$ with the desired properties.